# Let A and B be two independent event and P(A) = 2/5 and P(B) = 0.7. Calculate P(A U B)

Tags: probability, independence

(i) Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent event and $P(A) = 2/5$ and $P(B) = 0.7$. Calculate $P(A \cup B)$

(ii) If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive find $P(B|A)$ and $P(A|B)$.  Is it possible that $A$ and $B$ be independent?  Why?

(iii) If $P(A \cap B)>0$ then find $P(A \cup B|A\cap B)$

(iv) If $A$ and $B$ are independent and $P(A\cap B)>0$, calculate $P(A\cap B|A \cup B)$ when assumption in part $(i)$ holds

I solved part 1 by doing $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$. Since they are independent we know $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ so we have $P(A \cup B) = 0.4+0.7-(0.4\cdot 0.7) = 0.82$.

Comment: Question (ii) makes no sense.

Comment: sorry it should be find instead of and.

Comment: Assuming that $P(A)>0$ and $P(B)>0$ then you  have both conditional probabilities are zero.  It is questionable what value you would assign however if either or both are impossible events however.

Comment: You got the first right. Maybe it's only a matter of working on the other questions to answer them all. Definitions are all you need to complete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

(ii) $P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(\emptyset)}{P(B)}.$

(iii) $P(A \cup B \mid A \cap B) = \frac{P((A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B))}{P(A \cap B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cap B)}$.

(iv) $P(A \cap B \mid A \cup B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A \cup B)}$.

Comment: is P(A∩B) = P(0) because they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: @KGT Exactly right.

Comment: @KGT What is your definition of mutually exclusive?

Comment: Ok great and for part (iii), how did you get P((A∪B)∩(A∩B)) = P(A∩B)?

Comment: 2 event are mutually exclusive if they cant occur at the same time.

Comment: @KGT just use the definitions of $\cap$ and $\cup$. You should prove this yourself.

Comment: ok perfect. Thanks a lot for your help.